# How to replace the last unknow part of a file path using PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, replace, regexp-replace

I have folder pathes like

> \Street\House\Level\Room\321

or

> \City\Street\House\Level\Room\1023

and want to replace the last digits (here: 321 or 1023) with another number (i.e. 567) using PowerShell 5.1.

However the path can vary like the last digits can do.

How can this replacement be done?

I assume using RegEx, but I got lost regarding this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example a simple replace would do but assuming there could be numbers in other places in the string you can use a RegEx that captures one or more digits at the end of the string.

`\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times

`$` asserts position at the end of a line

```
[RegEx]::Replace('\Street\House\Level\Room\321', '\d+$', '1023')
[RegEx]::Replace('\City\Street\House\Level\Room\1023', '\d+$', '567')
```

Output:

```
\Street\House\Level\Room\1023
\City\Street\House\Level\Room\567
```

Comment: Great! However I had been unprecise when it comes to the "digits"; sorry for that. Instead they are "1.0.2.3", "3.2.1" and "5.6.7". That having said, the RegEx does not work anymore. Could you please assist another time?

Comment: @Joey, replace the regex pattern `\d+$` with `[\d.]+$` to get what you need

Comment: Horray! That's it! Thanks too.

Comment: Great @joey if this answered your question than please don’t forget to accept the answer